# Python - ctypes - accessing buffer return as pointer in dll library - datatranslation SDK

Tags: python, pointers, dll, ctypes

I'm working on a project using Datatranlation's DataAcq SDK.

I'm trying to access a buffer and set it's values.

example of how it is used in C:

```
/* allocate the output buffer, sets handler for buffer */
CHECKERROR (olDmCallocBuffer(0,0,(ULNG) size,2,&hbuf));
/* Get pointer to buffer */
CHECKERROR (olDmGetBufferPtr(board.hbuf,(LPVOID*)&lpbuf));

/* fill the output buffer*/

lpbuf[i] = (UINT) some value

/* Put the buffer to the DAC */

CHECKERROR (olDaPutBuffer(board.hdass, hbuf));
```

I am trying to do the same in Python using ctypes:

```
_buffer = ctypes.c_void_p()

    # Create buffer:
    check_error(memlib.olDmCallocBuffer(ctypes.c_uint(0x0000),
                                        ctypes.c_uint(0x0000),
                                        ctypes.c_uint(2),
                                        ctypes.c_uint(4),
                                        ctypes.byref(_buffer)))
    # Get pointer to buffer:
    buf_ptr = ctypes.c_void_p()
    check_error(memlib.olDmGetBufferPtr(_buffer, ctypes.byref(buf_ptr)))
```

But how can I access and set the elements as in the example in C above?
I can make a reference in Python I can modify but how to parse that back to the olDaPutBuffer function?

Edit:

Solved it with `memmove` from `ctypes` :

```
_buffer = ctypes.c_void_p()

# Create buffer:
check_error(memlib.olDmCallocBuffer(ctypes.c_uint(0x0000),
                                    ctypes.c_uint(0x0000),
                                    ctypes.c_uint(2),
                                    ctypes.c_uint(4),
                                    ctypes.byref(_buffer)))
# Get pointer to buffer:
buf_ptr = ctypes.c_void_p()
check_error(memlib.olDmGetBufferPtr(_buffer, ctypes.byref(buf_ptr)))

c_type_buf = ctypes.c_buffer(some values)
ctypes.memmove(buf_ptr, ctypes.byref(c_type_buf), len(c_type_buf))
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268294/python-ctypes-cdll-loadlibrary-instantiate-an-object-execute-its-method-priva/52272969#52272969, or at any question that involves *ctypes* first. For your question, take a look at `ctypes.Structure` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50447199/ctypes-struct-containing-arrays/50448338#50448338).

Comment: @CristiFati Thank you for the guidance and apologies for a badly worded question. I had a closer look at ctypes and ended up creating a buffer with `ctypes.c_buffer` and copy it to the address of the buffer pointer with `ctypes.mememove`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with `memmove` from `ctypes` :

```
_buffer = ctypes.c_void_p()

# Create buffer:
check_error(memlib.olDmCallocBuffer(ctypes.c_uint(0x0000),
                                    ctypes.c_uint(0x0000),
                                    ctypes.c_uint(2),
                                    ctypes.c_uint(4),
                                    ctypes.byref(_buffer)))
# Get pointer to buffer:
buf_ptr = ctypes.c_void_p()
check_error(memlib.olDmGetBufferPtr(_buffer, ctypes.byref(buf_ptr)))

# Create new buffer
c_type_buf = ctypes.c_buffer(some values)

# Copy new buffer to address of the original buffer
ctypes.memmove(buf_ptr, ctypes.byref(c_type_buf), len(c_type_buf))
```